# updating line in large text file using scala

Tags: scala, large-data, bigdata

i've a large text file around 43GB in .ttl contains triples in the form :

```
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1001> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <http://la.dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> .
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1001> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <http://lad.dbpedia.org/resource/Mohandas_Gandhi> .
```

and i want to find the fastest way to update a specific line inside the file without rewriting all next text. either by updating it or deleting it and appending it to the end of the file

to access the specific line i use this code :

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("text.txt").getLines
val seventhLine = lines drop(10000000) next
```

Comment: It seems using something so weakly structured as a "text file" (this is clearly *not* text, it just has fooled you into thinking it is) for this data storage seems like a clear mistake. Remember, too, that treating this data as text and writing code to manipulate the "lines" or as `String`s will mean you'll move at a very minimum 172 GB of data through your system, since each JVM `char` / Scala `Char` is two bytes so every byte read will have to be copied to a char array when read and back to a byte when written.

Comment: You should consider SQLite. With some careful tuning you can avoid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use text files, consider a *fixed* length/record size for each line/record.

This way you can use a `RandomAccessFile` to `seek` to the exact position of each line by number: You just seek to `line * LineSize`, and then update it.

It will not really help, if you have to *insert* a new line. Other limitations are: The file size will grow (because of the fixed record length), and there will always be one record which is too big.

As for the initial conversion:

- Get the maximum line length of the current file, then add 10% for example.
- Now you have to convert the file once: Read a line from the text file, and convert it into a fixed-size record.
- You could use a special character like `|` to separate the fields. If possible, use somthing like `;`, so you get a .csv file
- I suggest padding the remaining space it with spaces, so it still looks like a text file which you can parse with shell utilities.
- You could use a `\n` to terminate the record.

For example

```
http://x.com|http://x.com|http://x.com|...\n
```

or

```
http://x.com;http://x.com;http://x.com;...\n
```

where each `.` at the end represents a space character. So it's still somehow compatible with a "normal" text file.

---

On the other hand, looking at your data, consider using a key-value data store like Redis: You could use the line number or the 1st URL as the key.

Comment: it should be a small task that should be portable no need to install new infrastructure and libraries for redis , i go for RandomAccessFiles , but lines are not for fixed length , what's the best way to make it of fixed length what padding should i add ?

Comment: @Hady Elsahar I've updated the answer as the a possible scenario regarding the initial conversion.